# Singularities of determinantal varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need to investigate the singularities of determinantal varieties and I'm stuck finding a counter example. Here's the explanation.

My first case is this: Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $S=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $X$ be the Hankel matrix with $n$ variables

$$ X=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} &\cdots & x_{n-j+1} \\
   x_{2} & x_{3} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
    x_{3} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
   \vdots  & \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
   x_{j} & x_{j+1} & \cdots & \cdots & x_{n} 
  \end{pmatrix}$$

. Let $I_t(X)$ be the ideal generated by $t$-minors of $X$ and $V_t(X)$ be the variety generated by $I_t(X)$. Using Jacobian Criteria it's easy to prove that $\mathrm{Sing}(V_t(X))=V_{t-1}(X)$.

My second case is this: Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $X=(x_{i,j})_{1\leq i \leq m ,\ 1 \leq j \leq n }$ be a generic matrix and $S=K[X]$. Let $I_t(X)$ be the ideal generated by $t$-minors of $X$ and $V_t(X)$ be the variety generated by $I_t(X)$. Using Jacobian Criteria it's easy to prove that $\mathrm{Sing}(V_t(X))=V_{t-1}(X)$.

Both cases are easy to solve using Jacobian criteria. Moreover, it's easy to see that for any matrix $X$ with entries of linear form one has $\mathrm{Sing}(V_t(X))\supseteq V_{t-1}(X)$. However, it's unlikely to have equality. I've tried as many examples that I could've think of so far. If you have an example for which the equality does not hold, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Sepehr

Comment: What kind of example are you looking for? For instance, a matrix $X$ having homogeneous entries?

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for responding. Yes, I'm looking for a matrix with homogeneous entries for which $Sing(V_t(X)) \nsubseteq V_{t-1}(X)$.

Comment: And of course, I don't want to have elements of $K$ among the entries.

Comment: I don't see why $\operatorname{Sing}(V_t)\supseteq V_{t-1}$ should hold. Consider $X=\begin{pmatrix} x&x\\x&x\end{pmatrix}$, then $V_2(X) = K$ is smooth and  $V_1(X)$ is the origin. PS: If you ment the other inclusion, then this is an example where it is strict ;).

Comment: Sorry,  meant $I_{t}(X)\neq 0$ and entries of linear form. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: What is a Hankel matrix?